# how to implement a drop down list in Flutter without packages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I Need to implement a collapsible menu with pure dart in a flutter app 
So Any one can help please ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are building a `Material` app you should take a look at the [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) Widget.

Happy coding!